# How to Make Predictions of Data Using Sklearn's RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I followed this website here https://stackabuse.com/text-classification-with-python-and-scikit-learn/ and have successfully completed the model and saved it using my own data, however I don't know how to test a new document on the model. I have a bunch of documents in a string format like so: string = "Whatever and more of whatever" and I just need to know what code I need to run to test these documents through my model. My code is the exact same as the website with the only difference being the files I have loaded and to solve my problem I tried to use classifier.predict(string) and it gave me the error ValueError: could not convert string to float. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
import nltk
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
stemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
nltk.download('stopwords')
import pickle
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

doctor_data = load_files(r"pathtodata")
X, y = doctor_data.data, doctor_data.target

documents = []
for sen in range(0, len(X)):
    # Remove all the special characters
    document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X[sen]))

    # remove all single characters
    document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    document = document.lower()

    # Lemmatization
    document = document.split()

    document = [stemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in document]
    document = ' '.join(document)

    documents.append(document)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents).toarray()

tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
with open('text_classifier', 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump(classifier,picklefile)
```

**Update:**
I tried to convert my document to the proper format using this code

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(MYDOC).toarray()

tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(X).toarray()

pred = model.predict(X)
print(pred)
```

And this is the error I got 
                                                                  **ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 897 and input n_features is 149**

Comment: Hard to know what's your issue without the code, but you need to apply the same transformation to your new document as you did to the training one.

Comment: Sorry, here is my code. It works and dumps the data as a pickle file I can later access, but I don't know how to run a new document with this code

Comment: Apply the same transformation to the new document (minus the y target) as you did above to the training document, then run your classifier on it with .predict.

Comment: If you use this exact same code, your problem comes from the fact that you don't give the path to your data:
`doctor_data = load_files(r"pathtodata")`

Comment: NB: I just tried your code after downloading the dataset and it works. The result I have is the same as the tutorial:

`[[180  28]
 [ 30 162]]
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.86      0.87      0.86       208
          1       0.85      0.84      0.85       192

avg / total       0.85      0.85      0.85       400

0.855`

Comment: When I run the code it runs fine, but how would I run it with a new document to predict where the new document should go.

Comment: For new document, you would use the same `vectorizer` and `tfidfconverter` that you used on training data, but this time, you would only use `transform()` instead of `fit_transform()`

Comment: That gave me this error sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted and this one for when I changed tfidfcoverter sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: idf vector is not fitted

Comment: You are initializing a new `CountVectorizer(..)` object. I am telling you to use the original one. Same as you did for `model`.

Comment: It prints out an array like this [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4] which does match up to one of my datasets, but I get an array of 4's every time. This may just be the prediction my model is making, but I will do more test tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: What I mean by match up is that if I run     print(doctor_data.target_names[pred[0]]) I get one of my topics

Comment: So far all I get is an array of 4's in this format [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]

Comment: If I'm classifying tabular data does the test set have to have the exact column layout as the train set? How should my y variable column be formatted? All zeros? @VivekKumar